# What is the best query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, exists

I have the tables bus, street, route_going, route_return

In The table street I have

Example:

```
id | name
1  | street1 
2  | street2
3  | street4
...
n  | streetn
```

The table route_going, I have Example:

```
id_bus | id_street | order
101    | 1         | 1
101    | 2         | 2
101    | 5         | 3

...
```

The table route_return, I have example:

```
id_bus | id_street | order
101    | 3         | 1
101    | 2         | 2
101    | 1         | 3

...
```

Ok, in this example, the bus 101 travel from the streets 1,2 and 5, in this order. And the bus back from the streets 3,2 and 1, in this order.

I want to know which buses pass at the street 'x' and the street 'y' (first x, later y)

for example:

```
x = 1, y = 5 -> the bus 101 pass
x = 1, y = 3 -> the bus 101 pass
x = 3, y = 1 -> the bus 101 pass
x = 3, y = 5 -> the bus 101 don't pass
```

So, my sql for discover the buses is... (passing for the streets 1 and 5 for example)

```
select * from bus as b where 
-- The bus passes between the 2 streets at the going route??
exists (select * from route_going as rg1, route_going as rg2,street as r1,street as r2 where rg1.id_bus = rg2.id_bus and rg1.id_street = r1.id and rg2.id_street = r2.id and r1.id = 1 and r2.id = 5 and b.bus_id = rg1.id_bus and rg1.order <= rg2.order)
-- The bus passes between the 2 streets at the return route??
or exists (select * from route_return as rg1, route_return as rg2,street as r1,street as r2 where rg1.id_bus = rg2.id_bus and rg1.id_street = r1.id and rg2.id_street = r2.id and r1.id = 1 and r2.id = 5 and b.bus_id = rg1.id_bus and rg1.order <= rg2.order)
-- The bus passes between the 2 streets at the going route first and return route later??
or exists (select * from route_going as rg1, route_return as rg2,street as r1,street as r2 where rg1.id_bus = rg2.id_bus and rg1.id_street = r1.id and rg2.id_street = r2.id and r1.id = 1 and r2.id = 5 and b.bus_id = rg1.id_bus)
```

So, I think this query is not good. Can someone help me saying what the 'best' query for this search?

Comment: Could we have a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Please? Also, add information about your indexes. That could make a difference.

Comment: i don't understand, your code is doing way too many things to just be checking if a bus is passing through a street

Comment: @NoIdeaForName through **two** streets! in order!

Comment: @jpmc26 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0a7d/7

Comment: Can you modify the schema or are you stuck with it?

Comment: @jpmc26 I thought that I could join the tables route_going and route_return, would resolve the problem. But is the only best solution?

Comment: I think the part that really complicates the problem is the ordering requirement. If the question was simply, "Does it pass through these two streets?" it would be much simpler. It would also be simpler if going and returning didn't use the same numbers for ordering. (As in, if the returning values were always higher.) My initial thoughts were to combine the two route tables into a single table and add a column to indicate whether the bus was going/returning, and in that table, to use numbers that would fully order the streets in the route.

Comment: Another thing to consider: does the end result *have* to come from SQL? Or could you get some data from the database and then run a check in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @x = 1;
SET @y = 5;

SELECT x.id_bus
  FROM   
     ( SELECT *,0 returning FROM route_going UNION SELECT *, 1 FROM route_return ) x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT *,0 returning FROM route_going UNION SELECT *, 1 FROM route_return ) y
    ON y.id_bus = x.id_bus
   AND (y.returning > x.returning OR (y.returning = x.returning AND y.porder > x.porder))
 WHERE x.id_street = @x
   AND y.id_street = @y;
```

Comment: If you want DISTINCT results, use the DISTINCT operator.

Comment: I wonder if `UNION ALL` would give any performance gains. Because this specifies the `0` or `1` in the `UNION`, no rows will ever be the same, so the check for duplicate rows (if the engine performs it) is a waste of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
street.name,
route_going.id_bus,route_going.id_street
route_return.id_bus,route_return.id_street
on street.id=route_going.id_street and 
route_return.id_street=route_going.id_street;
```

try this. Thanks